# PHP/AJAX parse error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to take my PHP shoutbox and query using AJAX so that the page doesn't have to reload for shouts to be posted. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am stuck - I keep receiving a parse error:

```
18:47:27.216 Details: parsererror
Error:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data 1 index.php:100:4
```

I've got shoutBox.php, which holds the HTML and AJAX:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendChatMessage(msg)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login/postData.php",
        data: {
            thisPost: msg   
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data.error === false)
            {
                $("#aData").text(data);
                console.log("Post submitted.");
                ajax.reload();

            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Post was not submitted.");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err)
        {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div class="shoutbox">

    <h1 class="panel-heading"><strong>Federal</strong> Communications Array</h1>
    <hr>
    <ul class="shoutbox-content"></ul>

    <div class="panel">
    <form method="post">
    <p>
    <table border="0" align="center" style="height: auto;" width="90%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a></a></td>
                <td>

                <div class="input-group">

                    <span class="input-group-addon">Say:</span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="aData" name="post" maxlength='255' placeholder="Enter a message..."></input>

                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="sendChatMessage(document.getElementById('aData').value); return false;">Send</button>
                    </div>

                </div>


                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="100px">Timestamp</th>
                    <th width="120px">Username</th>
                    <th width="980px">Message</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>


        </table>
    </div>



</div>
```

And postData.php, which (is supposed to) execute the query.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

echo('Script begin.');

require "dbconf.php"; // db details

$connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($db_name,$connect);

$post = '';

    if(empty($_POST['aData'])) 
    {
        exit(json_encode([
        'error' => 'You must enter a message!',
        ]));

    } else {

        $post = trim($_POST['aData']);

        $playerUsername = $_SESSION['username'];

        $idQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `username`='$playerUsername'";

        $playeridQuery = mysql_query($idQuery);

        $playerID = mysql_result($playeridQuery, 0);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `shoutboxPosts` SET `id`='$playerID', `username`='$playerUsername', `post`='$post'");

    }



    exit(json_encode([
        'error' => false,
    ]));

?>
```

Comment: `echo('Script begin.');` <- Not JSON!

Comment: You are also open to SQL injections. Update your driver and use parameterized queries.

Comment: @chris85 I plan on implementing PDO - just finding the correct ajax method atm. Thank you.

Comment: Your AJAX fails because you tell you are returning JSON but per @HPierce comment you are generating invalid JSON. You also are sending error JSON on a successful insert.

Comment: @chris85 I did remove 'echo', and am still receiving the same parse error. Not really sure where it's originating.

Comment: Curl a POST to your PHP page and see what you get back for a response, is it JSON? Any errors would throw a parse error as well because of `display_errors`. Which could include deprecation notice of `mysql_`.

Comment: What is the output when you add `console.log(data)` at the beginning of your `success` function? There might be a PHP error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parse error come from this line:

$("#aData").text(data);

You can't send Json encoded data to a id in the DOM. You want see value of data,try this:

alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Other thing, in your php, avoid exit, forgot if and else.

Proper way is try, catch. You try, if error happend, catch exception.

Put a global variable outside your function and put the awswer inside.

After just:

echo json_encode($aswer);
$connect = null; // always close your connection.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove a single line

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

//echo('Script begin.'); Remove this line. It's violating JSON format

require "dbconf.php"; // db details

$connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($db_name,$connect);

$post = '';

    if(empty($_POST['aData'])) 
    {
        exit(json_encode([
        'error' => 'You must enter a message!',
        ]));

    } else {

        $post = trim($_POST['aData']);

        $playerUsername = $_SESSION['username'];

        $idQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `username`='$playerUsername'";

        $playeridQuery = mysql_query($idQuery);

        $playerID = mysql_result($playeridQuery, 0);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `shoutboxPosts` SET `id`='$playerID', `username`='$playerUsername', `post`='$post'");

    }



    exit(json_encode([
        'error' => false,
    ]));

?>
```

Comment: I removed that line and I am still receiving the same parse error at line 1 column 1.